# Excel - Auto fetching data from website to excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to write code which automatically could get data from the website, 
I would like to replace last part of the URL address (text: "22A") with any text I have in a cell, for example, "G1"

Code from recorded macro:

```
    Sub USA()
'
' USA N-numbers Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;http://www6.landings.com/cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr?pass=193800885&&nnumber=22A" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = "nph-search_nnr?pass=193800885&&nnumber=22A"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebTables = "18"
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 28.29
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 4.57
End Sub
```

When I replace 22A with Range("G1").Value I am getting Compile error: "Expected: list separator or )"
Anybody knows what is wrong in my coding?

Comment: ...cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr?pass=193800885&&nnumber=" Range("G1").Value
, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

Comment: "URL;http://www6.landings.com/cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr?     pass=193800885&&nnumber=" Range("G1").Value , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))                                                                                          I replaced it with the line above, still getting the same error and word Range gets highlited

Comment: Try `"URL;www6.landings.com/cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr? pass=193800885&&nnumber=" & Range("G1").Value`

Comment: Thank you @EEM , works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

`"URL;http://www6.landings.com/cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr?pass=193800885&&nnumber=22A"`

With:

`"URL;www6.landings.com/cgi-bin/nph-search_nnr? pass=193800885&&nnumber=" _
   & Range("G1").Value`